# Mysql High CPU Usage even optimazed conf

Tags: mysql, wildfly

I read all the answers about that problem and i haven't found any solution for this.

I have an application and fed from my api server. Wildfly 8.1 and Mysql 5.6. When peek time comes (Wildfly Server Connections About 2000-3000) Mysql uses all CPU. I gave 16 core CPU and it uses all of it.

Generaly i see %1500 CPU usage. I tried many ways that i could found but i still have this problem.

Can you help me to focus somewhere?

I only read data from mysql. Not too much write. I am not very good at Mysql. I am asking because of it. I installed Mysql by apt-get version 5.6. Can this cause problem?

Here is my conf. I have 8 GB ram. Ty.

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP

query_cache_type    = 1
query_cache_limit   = 2M
query_cache_size        = 100M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2

open_files_limit = 30000
table_open_cache = 7500
thread_cache_size = 25

join_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
max_allowed_packet = 10M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: inserts/updates/deletes or selects what type of queries are common? innodb?

Comment: When does this happen. Every time mysql is doing something? What are your queries? Please add more information.

Comment: No where near enough info. Also, why only a 3GB `innodb_buffer_pool_size` on an 8GB box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I solved it. i wasn't the designer of db. And i quick looked i saw some indexes. So i didn't think cause of that.

1 table has near 1 million row. And indexed but wrong indexes. So i indexed true columns. And CPU usage reduced from 16 Core to 2 Core.

So Index is important. Check your indexes twice.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can be configured to write a slow log, and there are good tools out there to summarize this slow log (even good old maatkit helps a lot and can be just downloaded without install). You can identify the queries which comsume most time in MySQL and then normally with `explain` and some indexes or with thinking a second time about the page you give the user you can reduce the load of MySQL.

Since your question is far too broad, there could be no exact solution to your problem.